# How to create the correct inherited class based on what is stored in the database

Tags: c#, linq, design-patterns

What Utility or Pattern can be used to solve this Issue?  I don't know what can be used to assist with this.  Can we use some type of pattern?

If you have the following abstract class:

```
abstract class Foo
{
    function void Something()
    {
    // Get the media type
    }
}
```

And the following classes that derive from that class:

```
class Foo1 : Foo
{
    public string MyId {get;set}
    public string MyFile {get;set}
    public TxtFile MyTextFile {get;set}

    function void myFooFunction()
    {
    // Save File to Txt
    }
}

class Foo2 : Foo
{
    public string MyId {get;set}
    public string MyFile {get;set}
    public XMLFile MyXMLFile {get;set}

    function MyOtherFunction()
    {
    // Save to XML
    }
}
```

Then in Linq (or Similar) within the repository you do something like this:

```
var a = (from e in db.myTable
        where e.myFileType == "XML"
        Select e);
```

Then we have to map this to the correct object. Like this:

```
Foo newFoo = FooFactory.CreateFooFor(a.myFileType.ToString())
newFoo.MyId = a.id;
newFoo.MyFile = a.myfile;
newFoo.MyXMLFile = a.xml;
```

The Factory certainly helps, but how do you do this for multiple "FileTypes" like txt for example?  The Fields wouldn't match up!

Do I have to write more code that does the same thing??
I feel like there has to be something that can do this.

Comment: Is this for a finite, known set of subclasses, or is it open for later extension?

Comment: I hadn't thought about that.  I suppose for now finite.

Comment: On the surface it looks like you should subclass a `File` class, not `Foo`. Then `Foo` just has a primitive property `FileType` by which it gets the right `File` subclass from a factory as and when a `File` is needed. The `File` class has a polymorphic `Save` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if `myFooFunction` and `MyOtherFunction` are both used to save, you can use the strategy pattern and just define and abstract `Save()` method to implement in derived classes. You might also look at the Template Method pattern.

Although this isn't exactly a pattern, you might also want to apply the "Pull Up Field" refactoring here and put the `MyId` and `MyFile` properties in the parent class.

For creation...

The Builder pattern is similar to the factory, but allows for more complex object creation. I don't know how well it fits this simplified example, but it might fit what you are actually trying to do in your real code. Probably not. I just mention it first because it is the closest to factory in my mind.

There are also the Mapper Pattern and the Data Mapper Pattern. You might encapsulate the mapping in an object and have the factory return a mapper:

```
    FooMapper mapper = FooMapperFactory.CreateFooMapperFor(a.myFileType);
    Foo newFoo = mapper.CreateFoo(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you consider using [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx) on the data that's returned from the database, or perhaps the [Adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) you can set up a dynamic way to map fields to each other. Using reflection (the following is pseudo logic as reflection is kind of messy code to provide):

- Get a list of PropertyInfo objects for all public properties from the target type
- Get a list of PropertyInfo objects for all public properties from the database type
- Compare their names/types to create the mapping
- Assign values from the database type, using reflection, to the target type

Something like this will do the trick:

```
public void AssignAndMapTypes<DatabaseType, TargetType>(DatabaseType db, ref TargetType target)
    {
        var dbType = db.GetType();
        var dbTypeProperties = dbType.GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public);

        var targetType = target.GetType();
        var targetTypeProperties = targetType.GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public);

        foreach (var prop in targetTypeProperties)
        {
            var matchingProp = dbTypeProperties.Where(e => { return (string.Compare(e.Name, prop.Name, true) == 0) && (e.PropertyType == prop.PropertyType) }).FirstOrDefault();

            if(matchingProp != null)
            {
                prop.SetValue(target, matchingProp.GetValue(db, null), null);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could solve your problem using generics. I took the liberty of changing around some code.  Would this work?

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    public abstract void Save();
    public void Something()
    {
        // Get the media type
    }
}

public class FooText : Foo
{
    public string MyId { get; set; }
    public string MyFile { get; set; }
    public string MyTextFile { get; set; }

    public override void Save()
    {
        // Save File to Txt
    }
}

public class FooXml : Foo
{
    public string MyId { get; set; }
    public string MyFile { get; set; }
    public string MyXMLFile { get; set; }

    public override void Save()
    {
        // Save to XML
    }
}

public class FooFactory<T> where T : Foo, new()
{
    public static T CreateFoo()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```